# Android Json Image parsing error

Tags: android, json

i have parsed json data and set to list view . When i click on list view object(image) it is showing error. What i should do.

android.content.ContextWrapper.getCacheDir(ContextWrapper.java:208)

Comment: If you have a new question, please post it as a separate question rather than editing your old question to be something completely different and thus rendering the answer irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your just beginning with Xamarin then a WebClient should do the trick, it's really straight forward.

```
private void SendSomeData (string url)
{
   WebClient client = new WebClient();

   //POST variables
   NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection();
   parameters.Add("Key1", "Value1");
   parameters.Add("Key2", "Value2");

   //register a callback
   client.UploadValuesCompleted += (object sender, UploadValuesCompletedEventArgs e) =>
   {
      if (e.Result != null)
      {
          //you'll need to download and reference Json.Net
          string jsonData = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(e.Result);
                    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyCustomClass>(jsonData);
      }
    };

    //Don't forget to call it :)
    client.UploadValuesAsync(new Uri(url), parameters); 
}
```

Hope this helps, if you're looking for something more modern look into HttpClient, you may have to familiarize yourself with asynchronous programming with C# however.

Comment: could u update me a total code.how to send data to server using url and json parsing also...

Comment: I actually have some videos that demonstrate exactly what your are trying to, take a look. https://youtu.be/jF3D__ibrx8